# Go template checking for current page for nav bar

Tags: go

I'm trying to set a li in a golang template to active based on the current page. From what I've read you can only do {{if .scoreheader}} to check existence of a variable. Is there another way around this?

```
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">

        {{range $id, $name := .test}}
            {{if $name == .scoreheader}}
            <li class="active">
            {{else}}
            <li>
            {{end}}
            <li><a href="/app/index/?company={{$id}}">{{$name}}</a></li>
        {{end}}
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `eq` function as explained in [`text/template`](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#pkg-overview):

> There is also a set of binary comparison operators defined as
>   functions:
>
> eq    Returns the boolean truth of arg1 == arg2

So your if-statement would be:

```
{{if eq $name $.scoreheader}}
```

Comment: Had to do: {{$scoreheader := .scoreheader}} before then {{if eq $name $scoreheader}} but it works. Thank you!

Comment: Ah, the . has the inner value in the loop. I changed to `{{if eq $name $.scoreheader}}` which should also work. $ refers to the initial value of . (dot).